# IStringLocalizer injection .Net Core 2.2

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dependency-injection

I'm trying to inject IStringLocalizer into some custom component (of different library).

In my Startup class I have the following code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
     services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
     services.AddMvc(...);
     services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
            {
                new CultureInfo("en"),
                new CultureInfo("ru-RU")
            };

            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "en", uiCulture: "en");
            options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;

            options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new CustomRequestCultureProvider(context =>
            {
                var userLangs = context.Request.Headers["Accept-Language"].ToString();
                var firstLang = userLangs.Split(',').FirstOrDefault();
                var defaultLang = string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstLang) ? "en" : firstLang;
                return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult(defaultLang, defaultLang));
            }));
        });
       //code
       services.AddSomeService(Configuration);
   }
```

and then

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
   //code
   var options = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
   app.UseRequestLocalization(options.Value);
   app.UseMvc();
   //code
}
```

AddSomeService method is an extension method that contains line like:

```
services.AddScoped<IValidationMessageProvider>(provider => 
   new StringLocalizerValidationMessagesProvider(provider.GetRequiredService<IStringLocalizer>()));
```

unfortunately provider.GetRequiredService() throws exception "'No service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.IStringLocalizer' has been registered.'", so I cannot use it in my custom component StringLocalizerValidationMessagesProvider. I have a folder named "Resources" with "ValidationResources.resx" in it with access modifier set as Public.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Same issue for me. No solution, yet?

Comment: Have you tried to specify generic version supplying Resource class name like `IStringLocalizer<ResourceClassName>` if applicable?